# Difficulties on understand a particular derivative of position vector field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, calculus

Please, I'm struggling on this particular second derivative:

$\vec{r} = \vec{r}[\vec{r}'(t),t] $
Then in component form: $x^k = x^{k}[x'^{h}(t),t]$

I know that we have an chain rule:

$ \displaystyle \frac{dx^k }{dt} = \sum_{i}\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial x'^{h}}\frac{dx'^h }{dt} + \frac{\partial x^k}{\partial t}  $

Ok, but now in second differentiation, I really don't know how to manage quite well.

$$ \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dx^k }{dt}\right) = \frac{d}{dt}\left(\sum_{\color{red}{h}}\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial x'^{h}}\frac{dx'^h }{dt} + \frac{\partial x^k}{\partial t} \right) =  \frac{d}{dt}\left(\sum_{\color{red}{h}}\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial x'^{h}}\frac{dx'^h }{dt}\right) + \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial t} \right) 
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dd}[2]{\frac{{\rm d}#1}{{\rm d}#2}}$
$\newcommand{pd}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$
$\newcommand{\ddtwo}[2]{\frac{{\rm d^2}#1}{{\rm d}#2^2}}$
$\newcommand{pdtwo}[2]{\frac{\partial^2 #1}{\partial #2^2}}$
$\newcommand{pdthree}[3]{\frac{\partial^2 #1}{\partial #2\partial #3}}$

If $x^k = x^k(x'^h(t),t)$ then

$$
\dd{x^k}{t} = \sum_i \pd{x^k}{x'^i}\dd{x'^i}{t} + \pd{x^k}{t}
$$

And

\begin{eqnarray}
\ddtwo{x^k}{t} &=& \sum_i \dd{}{t}\left( \pd{x^k}{x'^i}\dd{x'^i}{t} \right) + \dd{}{t}\pd{x^k}{t} \\
&=& \sum_i \left(\dd{}{t} \pd{x^k}{x'^i}\right)\dd{x'^i}{t}  + \pd{x^k}{x'^i}\left(\dd{}{t}\dd{x'^i}{t} \right)  + \dd{}{t}\pd{x^k}{t} \\
&=& \sum_i \left(\sum_j\pdthree{x^k}{x'^i}{x'^j}\dd{x'^j}{t} + \pdthree{x^k}{x'^i}{t}\right)\dd{x'^i}{t} + \pd{x^k}{x'^i}\left(\ddtwo{x'^i}{t}\right) + \sum_j\pdthree{x^k}{t}{x'^j}\dd{x'^j}{t} + \pdtwo{x^k}{t}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: I don't know why $x'^{j}$ appears and I don't know how to compute:

$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial x'^i})$ and $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial t})$

Comment: Call $u= \partial x^k/\partial x'^i$. Cleary $u = u(x'(t),t)$, so the same rule applies

$$
\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}t} = \sum_j \frac{\partial u}{\partial x'^j}\frac{{\rm d}x'^j}{{\rm d}t} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}
$$